# How to Add Content, allow a user to Add Content and assign the Front Page in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need a refresher course on Drupal.  I have a new installation of Drupal 7 and I have "No front page content has been created yet".  How do I configure this front page?  How do I give a new user the ability to create their own blogs whilst also preventing them from having full control of the system?

Answer (score 2):

Front page is set under "site information"
admin/config/system/site-information

permissions are set with roles and permissions
admin/people/permissions